# complex query with distinct and top value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I need to get a distinct list where there is one field that may have multiple entries for the same row.  To clarify, I have two fields CN and PN which together normally make a unique set, however in some cases they combine with CC to make multiple lines.  The set would look like this:

```
CN                PN           CC
123               123          C23
123               123          C24
124               124          C23
```

So in most cases the result of distinct produces the row where CN = 124.   In a few of the cases the result is like CN = 123 where you have two different CCs.  If I just use a select distinct query, I get the result set above.  What I am looking for is one row for 123 and one row for 124.  the CC that would be applicable would need to be C23 for both.  What my client is actually asking for is to select the CC based on a criteria she has for the most important CC value is.  She wants C23 first, C24 second, C52 third and C37 fourth.

I think I can do this in a two step process where I select distinct of everything except CC and then join to the table with the CC information after getting a unique set based on the CN and PN.

I am happy to answer any questions or concerns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_Number()` for this prioritization query:

```
select cn, pn, cc
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by cn, pn
                                order by charindex(cc, 'C23,C24,C52,C37')
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The `charindex()` is just a shorthand for ordering the values; it will not work under all circumstances (but is convenient and easy-to-read).  The more traditional way would be `(case cc when 'C23' then 1 when 'C24' then 2 when 'C52' then 3 when 'C37' then 4 else 5 end)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution, see if it works for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT CN, PN FROM [Table]) t
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP 1 CC 
    FROM [Table] t0 
    WHERE t0.CN = t.CN AND t0.PN = t.PN 
    ORDER BY CASE CC WHEN 'C23' THEN 0 WHEN 'C24' THEN 1 WHEN 'C52' THEN 2 WHEN 'C37' THEN 3 END
) t1
```